# checking that `malloc` succeeded in C

Tags: c, malloc

I want to allocate memory using `malloc` and check that it succeeded. something like:

```
if (!(new_list=(vlist)malloc(sizeof (var_list))))
  return -1;
```

how do I check success?

Comment: Your code already does check success. On failure it returns -1, on success it carries on to the next line. I hope `vlist` is a typedef for `var_list*`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`malloc` returns a null pointer on failure. So, if what you received isn't null, then it points to a valid block of memory.

Since `NULL` evaluates to false in an `if` statement, you can check it in a very straightforward manner:

```
value = malloc(...);
if(value)
{
    // value isn't null
}
else
{
    // value is null
}
```

Comment: Zero can be used wherever NULL is appropriate, but NULL is not zero. It's NULL. It does always evaluate to false, though.

Comment: @Phillip My bad, I wrongly assumed that C was like C++ in this regard.

Comment: in C (unlike C++) `(void*)0` is a null pointer constant. That's because a `void*` pointer in C (unlike C++) can be implicitly converted to any other pointer type, so it's possible to allow NULL to have `void*` type. So in both languages NULL is an implementation-defined null pointer constant, but C implementations have more freedom.

Comment: On some platforms NULL might not be 0 but some addr like 0xFFEE0000 so to be on a safe side and portable I would go with an explicit if (value != NULL)

Comment: @Alex `NULL` is a _null pointer constant_, and that is guaranteed to evaluate to zero. If your particular implementation doesn't comply with the standard, I feel sorry for you, but on sane platforms you don't need that kind of check.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Yep, you are right. The null pointer value sometimes might be other then 0, but it's guaranteed to evaluate to zero.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Actually I gave it a thought and now I think I know why I doesn't like it. Readability issue. value is not a boolean expression and I consider it's a bad habit (encapsulated for over 30 years now) write code like if(!value), that's why C++ has an explicit keyword nullptr exactly for that reason; and in other languages like java and c# you cannot write something like if(!value) for a pointer. Even in C, especially in embedded mixing up 0 (zero) and null pointer may lead to some unpleasant side effects.

Answer (score 8):

Man page :

> If successful, `calloc()`, `malloc()`, `realloc()`, `reallocf()`, and `valloc()` functions return a pointer to allocated memory.  If there is an error, they return a `NULL` pointer and set `errno` to `ENOMEM`.

Answer (score 8):

```
new_list=(vlist)malloc(sizeof (var_list)
if (new_list != NULL) {
  /* succeeded */
} else {
  /* failed */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have already tests for error, although I normally write the assignment and check as two separate lines:

```
new_list = malloc(sizeof *new_list);
if (!new_list)
    /* error handling here */;
```

(Note two small changes - you shouldn't cast the return value, and we take the size from the variable rather than its type to reduce the chance of a mismatch).

If `malloc()` fails, it returns a null pointer, which is the only pointer value that is *false*.

The error handling you have is simply `return -1;` - how you handle that in the calling function is up to you, really.