# Pass by address, scanf, de-referencing

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, scanf

I have written a program employing the following concept:

I create an integer `x` pass by address to a function, along with a filename, said function opens file if available, scans the first line and sets the value that `pX` points to equal to the scanned line.

Only it's not working, and I don't see what I'm doing wrong. As far as I can tell the code below is generally how one would accomplish it, but I'm not sure if I'm not using `scanf()` correctly with the pointer or what.

```
void foo() {
    char input[20] = "test.txt";
    int x = 1;
    bar(input, &x);
}

void bar(char *fileName, int *pX) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char *buffer = malloc(15 * sizeof(int));
    fgets(buffer, 15, fp);
    scanf(buffer, "%d", *pX);
    free(buffer);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: The `scanf` function wants pointers for the arguments. `pX` is a pointer. `*pX` is *not* a pointer.

Comment: `scanf(buffer, "%d", *pX);`....what the compiler said?

Comment: @SouravGhosh compiles.

Comment: `15 * sizeof(int)` You're allocating more size than what you need. You probably wanted `15 * sizeof(char)` which is the same as `15` as `sizeof(char)` is equal to 1

Comment: Please please turn up your compiler warning level (`-Wall -Wextra` for *gcc* and *clang*). If your compiler does not provide proper warnings, please switch compiler. Then fix the warnings you get (ask here if you don't understand them or don't know how to fix, it's easy to write a good quality question for something that straightforward).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change line :

```
scanf(buffer, "%d", *pX);
```

to :

```
sscanf(buffer, "%d", pX);
```

You need function [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) for what you are trying to do.

Both `scanf` and `sscanf` take a pointer as an argument. `pX` is of type `int *`, therefore a pointer to an `int` and should work for you. What you pass, `*pX`, is the *contents* of this pointer, in other words an `int`.

Also, change line :

```
char *buffer = malloc(15 * sizeof(int));
```

to :

```
char *buffer = malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
```

or simply :

```
char *buffer = malloc(15);
```

and always [check the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607455/checking-that-malloc-succeeded-in-c) :

```
if (buffer == NULL){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be : scanf(buffer, "%d", pX); ??

Comment: `scanf(buffer, "%d", pX);` are you sure this is even valid?

Comment: thank you. sscanf(buffer, "%d", pX); solved my issue.

Comment: IMO, `buffer = malloc(sizeof *buffer * 15);` is even better for allocations.  No need to code the matching type.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's no pass-by-reference in C, function parameters are all passed by value. By passing a pointer-to-data, we make the simulation of the achieving the same effect as pass-by-reference, but that does not mean C has any pass-by-reference concept.

That said, the problem seems to be

```
 scanf(buffer, "%d", *pX);
                     ^^^^
```

where

- the current syntax is invalid and invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Probably you need [`sscanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).
- `px` is already a pointer to `int`. Passing `px` will be correct and suffice.

Moral of the story: enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them. They are there for a reason. With proper warnings enabled, you should see something like

> warning: format `%d` expects argument of type `int *`, but argument 3 has type `int` [`-Wformat=`]

Finally,

- Always check the return value of `fopen()` for success before using the file pointer.
- Check for the return value of `scanf()` to ensure successful scanning.
- Check for the return value of `fgets()` to ensure success

...basically, check return value of all library calls to make sure they worked *as expected*.

Comment: I've tried this. It doesn't seem to work. At least in the actual program I'm writing.

Comment: `scanf` should be `sscanf` here

Comment: @wanderbread If you already know, great!! Let's allow it to be there for whom might be a little more confused, shall we?

Answer (score 1):

You use `scanf()` incorrectly: either use `scanf` directly to parse standard input or use `sscanf()` to parse the string read by `fgets()`. Furthermore, `pX` is already a pointer to `int`, which is what `sscanf()` expects to store the `int` value it converts, pass it directly: `sscanf(buffer, "%d", pX);`

Here is a modified version:

```
int bar(const char *fileName, int *pX) {
    char buffer[15];
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    int success = 0;

    if (fp != NULL) {
        fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp);
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", pX) == 1)
            success = 1;
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return success;
}

void foo(void) {
    int x = 1;
    bar("test.txt", &x);
    /* do something with x */
}
```

Notes:

- allocating `buf` is unnecessary, just make it a local array with automatic storage.
- `char *buffer = malloc(15 * sizeof(int));` is incorrect: you allocate space for 15 `int` instead of 15 characters, which have a size of 1 by definition. Use the size of the destination type to avoid any inconsistencies:

  ```
  char *buffer = malloc(15 * sizeof(*buffer));
  ```
- always check the return value of `malloc()` to avoid potential undefined behavior.
- reading from `fp` without checking if `fopen` succeeded has potential undefined behavior.
- the contents of the array pointed to by `filename` is not modified, make it a `const char *`.
- it may be useful for `bar` to return a success indicator.
- enable more warnings at compile time: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` or `clang -Weverything -Werror` might have caught the mistakes in `scanf`.

Comment: What do you mean be automatic storage? In my actual application I need to be able to handle potentially very large files. Allocation based on the whole file size seemed redundant but an effective way to make sure that was possible.

Comment: Also thank you for the suggestion of including the "-Weverything" and "-Werror" arguments. This is great, and will help immensely in the future. Is there anyway I can turn this options on permanently?

Comment: @wanderbread: automatic storage is the default for local variables in function scope, as opposed to static storage with the `static` keyword.  A small buffer, up to a few kilobytes are OK for automatic storage, larger arrays should be allocated from the heap and freed after use.