# Malloc stack overflow

Tags: c, malloc

Guys below code works fine until size= 100000. However it gives me stack overflow error after size=200000. 
How can i fix that ? 
Is there some way to optimize it ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define SIZE 500000
// HELPER ARRAY FUNCTIONS
void check(int *arr)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>arr[i + 1])
        {
            printf("Not sorted.\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Sorted.\n");
}
void fill_array(int *arr)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        arr[i] =rand()%100;
}
void print_array(int *arr)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
// NODE STRUCT
typedef struct BST_NODE
{
    struct BST_NODE *left, *right;
    int data;
}node;
// TREE FUNCTIONS
node* generate_node(int *value)
{
    node *n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    n->data = *value;
    return n;
}
node* insert_node(node *n, int *value)
{
    if (n == NULL)
        return generate_node(value);
    if (*value < n->data)
        n->left = insert_node(n->left, value);
    else
        n->right = insert_node(n->right, value);
    return n;
}
node* construct_BST(int *arr, node* n)
{
    int i;
    n = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        n = insert_node(n, &arr[i]);
    return n;
}
int s = 0;
void LVR(int *arr, node* n)
{
    if (n != NULL)
    {
        LVR(arr, n->left);
        arr[s] = n->data;
        s++;
        LVR(arr, n->right);
    }
}
void tree_sort(int *arr)
{
    node *root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    root = construct_BST(arr, root);
    LVR(arr, root);
}
// DRIVER PROGRAM
int main()
{
    int *Array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);
    fill_array(Array);
    tree_sort(Array);
    print_array(Array);
    check(Array);
    free(Array);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

It gives an error at this part below:

```
node* generate_node(int *value)
{
    node *n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    n->data = *value;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think there is a stack overflow?

Comment: "Malloc stack overflow" - `malloc` allocates memory on the heap, it returns a pointer to the allocated memory chunk. If it fails, it returns 0 (`NULL`). You better check the `malloc`'s return value before using it. Stack overflow has nothing to do with `malloc`. So what error **exactly** do you get?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @AlexLop yes the exact error is stack overflow as visual studio tells me. This is why i'm stuck

Comment: You should consider checking if `malloc` succeeded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607455/checking-that-malloc-succeeded-in-c

Comment: It is probably an overflow on the only recursive stack operation in this code during tree-build, namely the `insert_node` invokes. I'd check your logic there.

Comment: If you're getting a stack overflow it won't be because of the `malloc`. It'll be because something went wrong before the `malloc`. The `malloc`'s the poor sucker who happened to walk by the scene of the crime after and got picked up by the cops.

Comment: @schil227 yes it succeeds everytime. Maybe something else causes the error.

Comment: @WhozCraig I even tried sending reference instead of value on that function. But still no good.

Comment: That's not going to solve the issue. You're building an unbalanced tree that could *easily* degenerate to long chains of linked lists, and with that generate extremely long call chains as you recurse for your insertions.

Comment: @WhozCraig Would you recommend an iterative version of it ? Or else ?

Comment: Absolutely. And in fact, I would rec not using a tree for this at all, though I imagine it is for academia. For your limited domain (0...99) and very large count, I would totally use a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) for this task, the speed of which would be blistering. It has very, *very* limited application, but this specific task fits it *perfectly*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for your fast responces :) I'll work onto it.

Comment: Change the same value to count-up without creating a new node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by other people, the problem is that the depth of the tree will be `SIZE` in the worst case.

In the case of your code, since the value to hold is a value less than 100, you can suppress the depth of the tree by not creating a new node for the same value.

In case of the same value change  to count up as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //stdlib.h include malloc and free

#define SIZE 500000


typedef struct BST_NODE {
    struct BST_NODE *left, *right;
    int data;
    int count;//Add for count
} node;

node* generate_node(int value){//just use int
    node *n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));//C does not need to cast from  void *.
    n->right = n->left = NULL;
    n->data = value;
    n->count = 1;//set 1 at first time
    return n;
}

node* insert_node(node *n, int value){
    if(n == NULL)
        return generate_node(value);
    if(value < n->data)
        n->left = insert_node(n->left, value);
    else if (value > n->data)
        n->right = insert_node(n->right, value);
    else
        n->count++;//Add count up
    return n;
}

node* construct_BST(int *arr){//no need node *n as argument 
    int i;
    node *n = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        n = insert_node(n, arr[i]);
    return n;
}

int s = 0;
void LVR(int *arr, node *n){
    if (n != NULL){
        int i;
        LVR(arr, n->left);
        for(i = 0; i < n->count; ++i)
            arr[s++] = n->data;//Repeat as many times as count
        LVR(arr, n->right);
    }
}

void tree_free(node *n){
    if(n){
        tree_free(n->left);
        tree_free(n->right);
        free(n);
    }
}

void tree_sort(int *arr){
    node *root = construct_BST(arr);
    s = 0;//Necessary for different calls
    LVR(arr, root);
    tree_free(root);//release tree
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a stack overflow, that means your function call stack is getting too deep.  That can happen when building a binary search tree if the tree ends up being unbalanced.

Best case, your tree height will be `O(log n)`, worst case it will be `O(n)`.  If you place items into the tree in sorted order, your binary tree will degenerate into a linked list and you'll hit the worst case.

For this particular example, you're generating random numbers from 0 to 99.  You might get more randomize results if you increase the range of the numbers.  So instead of using `rand()%100`, use something like `rand()%10000`.  That might help keep the height of the tree down.

On an unrelated note, you have a memory leak.  First, the initial node you allocate for the root of the tree gets overwritten, so you don't need it.  Second, you never bother to free the tree structure.

You can take care of these as follows:

```
void free_tree(node *root)
{
    if (root) {
        free_tree(root->left);
        free_tree(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
}

void tree_sort(int *arr)
{
    node *root = NULL
    root = construct_BST(arr, root);
    LVR(arr, root);
    free_tree(root);
}
```